# How to restrict making changes on a subscriber end who published the changes in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have 3 events attached to a firebase reference as below

`

```
fileRef.on('child_changed' , function(snapshot){
    var file = snapshot.val()
    changeFile()
})
fileRef.on('child_removed' , function(snapshot){
    var file = snapshot.val()
    removeFile()
})
fileRef.on('child_added' , function(snapshot){
    var file = snapshot.val()
    createFile()
})
```

`
Whenever the subscriber changes the content of file the same event 'child_changed' is fired on subscriber who is making changes. As user as already done the changes locally I don't want changeFile to fire twice. How can I avoid this? I tried using a single variable to distinguish but sometimes there are series of events which is fired continuously so I am not sure if that can work.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should follow the [CQRS pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) when making changes with Firebase. In this approach you write any changes to the database, and then visualize those changes when the event fires back from Firebase. It sounds like that isn't possible for you, but I'd still recommend considering it.

There is nothing built into Firebase to prevent the listener from firing for local events. But you can track each write that the local client starts (for example by keeping track of the push ID of each item that you write), and then filter those IDs out in your `on("child_` handlers.

For example to keep track of the keys:

```
var newRef = ref.push(newData);
var newKey = newRef.key;
```

And then in your listener:

```
if (snapshot.key != newKey) {
  ...
}
```

Of course if there can be multiple pending writes from the local client, you'll want to track those in an array.

Comment: let's say I keep a track of IDs in an array and when the child handlers are fired I will check as you have mentioned. But when should I make this array empty? because sometimes if I update 4-5 children at a same time using update() then firebase events are also fired 4-5 times

Comment: When you see a `child_` event for something you tracked, you can remove that ID. If you update multiple children, track the individual keys (as that's where the `child_` events will fire).